# combining rows with CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, case

```
Customer_id   item_type   item_code
1             a           123
1             b           456
1             c           789
```

I've used CASE to split 'item_code' into different columns based on what is contained in the 'item_type' column. All date from same table.

```
customer_id   item_type_a   item_type_b   item_type_c
1             123
1                            456
1                                         789
```

However, what I really need to do it output to one line.

```
customer_id   item_type_a   item_type_b   item_type_c
1             123           456           789
```

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You can't combine rows with `CASE`.  That's a scalar function, it just takes a bunch of input values and returns a single value.  To "combine rows" you use `GROUP BY`.  You can, however, use both together...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select customer_id,
       max(case when item_type = 'a' then item_code end) as item_type_a,
       max(case when item_type = 'b' then item_code end) as item_type_b,
       max(case when item_type = 'c' then item_code end) as item_type_c
from t
group by customer_id;
```

Comment: Does it really work? Because when I tried this I got result not as expected. I am getting CUSTOMER_ID ITEM_TYPE_A ITEM_TYPE_B ITEM_TYPE_C
1 123 null null
3 null null 789
2 null 456 null

Comment: @Shaili - Then you've given each row a different customer ID.  They should all be `1` in the OP's example.

Comment: Each customer_id will have one of each item_type a, b and c, but the item_code value is always unique. So this works perfectly for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `correlated subquery` as an alternative option :

```
select max(customer_id) as customer_id,
       ( select item_code from tab t where t.customer_id = r.customer_id and 'a' = r.item_type ) 
        as item_type_a,
       ( select item_code from tab t where t.customer_id = r.customer_id and 'b' = r.item_type ) 
        as item_type_b, 
       ( select item_code from tab t where t.customer_id = r.customer_id and 'c' = r.item_type ) 
        as item_type_c
  from tab r 
 group by r.customer_id;
```

alternatively, you may create a function as

```
create or replace function get_item_code( 
                                         i_item_type   tab.item_type%type,
                                         i_customer_id tab.customer_id%type
                                         ) is
 o_item_code tab.item_code%type  
begin
 select item_code
   into o_item_code 
   from tab t 
  where t.customer_id = i_customer_id 
    and t.item_type = i_item_type;

  return o_item_code;

 exception when no_data_found then return null;
end;
```

an then issue

```
select max(customer_id) as customer_id,
       get_item_code('a',customer_id) as item_type_a,
       get_item_code('b',customer_id) as item_type_b,
       get_item_code('c',customer_id) as item_type_c
  from tab 
 group by customer_id;
```

Comment: Why this rather than simple conditional aggregation?  *(This will scan and also have multiple seeks, where as simple conditional aggregation will just have the scan...)*

Comment: @MatBailie personally I also prefer using conditional aggregation from the point of performance gain, especially in a production environment. Gordon already mentioned about that, I presented this as an alternative case. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the merit is in adding an answer that is longer, more complicated, and has worse performance...  I'm not saying don't add it, I'm asking, what's the merit of this particular answer?  Why would it ever be a legitimate option, what does it give that is worth considering?

Comment: @MatBailie discounting the performance gain,the complexity might be solved by creating a function including that select to replace all those statements.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the other given valid and correct answers, there's also `PIVOT` clause you can use, actually created for exactly such cases (where you want to switch from row-based data organization, to column-based data organization).
It looks like this:

```
select *
from tab
pivot (
  max(item_code)
  for (item_type)
  in ('a' as item_type_a, 'b' as item_type_b, 'c' as item_type_c)
)
order by customer_id
```

For this sample data:

```
CUSTOMER_ID | ITEM_TYPE | ITEM_CODE
------------+-----------+----------
          1 | a         | 123
          1 | b         | 456
          1 | c         | 789
          2 | a         | ABC
          2 | b         | DEF
          2 | c         | GHI
          3 | a         | XYZ
          3 | b         | PQR
          4 | a         | MMM
          4 | a         | NNN
```

It gives those results:

```
CUSTOMER_ID | ITEM_TYPE_A | ITEM_TYPE_B | ITEM_TYPE_C
------------+-------------+-------------+------------
          1 | 123         | 456         | 789
          2 | ABC         | DEF         | GHI
          3 | XYZ         | PQR         |
          4 | NNN         |             |
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0086e/4/1) how it works in action (and comparison to equivalent query based on `GROUP BY`).
As you can see, it has basically the same execution plan as the `GROUP BY` queries, so is rather usable more for clarity, than for performance. It's also worth mentioning, that `PIVOT` was not available prior to Oracle 11g, so if you are also targeting older versions, then `GROUP BY` is your choice.

You have not specified how to address cases, when there are multiple rows with the same combination of `customer_id` and `item_type` (see case with `customer_id` equal to 4 in my sample data). I've used same approach as others with the `GROUP BY`, so I chose `MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to keep your table you can use:

```
select customer_id,
       max(item_type_a) as item_type_a,
       max(item_type_b) as item_type_b,
       max(item_type_c) as item_type_c
from tableName
group by customer_id;
```

EDIT:

i'm assuming that his solution with the table (customer_id item_type_a item_type_b item_type_c) is the base for this query

Comment: Where is the column as item_type_a, item_type_b and item_type_c as base table is only one column item_type

Comment: you need to put `FROM (the query you tried with a CASE expression in it) AS source` rather than `FROM tableName`

Comment: i'm assuming that his solution with the table (customer_id   item_type_a   item_type_b   item_type_c) is the base for this query

Comment: Then say that in your answer.